# How to find modulus of two uint64 values

Tags: objective-c, modulus

Pretty simple question really.  I have two uint64 values.  I want to divide the two numbers and get the remainder.

```
 uint64 number1 = 36556800;
 uint64 number2 = 59325441;
 uint64 result = number1 % number2;
 NSLog(@"Result: %lld", result);
```

The above code always prints the value of number1 (36556800).

EDIT: I realize that number1 is less than number2.  When you divide these two numbers the result is a fraction.  I want to capture that fraction.  So basically in my example:

```
 36556800 / 59325441 = 0.6162
```

How do I get 6162 into a variable?  Integer division discards the fraction so isn't the modulus operator what I should be using?

Comment: Well it's easy : number1 < number2. => using the modulo operator you'll always get number1 as the remainder since the result of the division is below 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many times does 59325441 go into 36556800?

Zero times, because 59325441 is greater than 36556800.

How much is left when you subtract 0 * 59325441 from 36556800?

```
36556800 - 0 * 59325441 == 36556800
```

Therefore

```
36556800 % 59325441 == 36556800
```

Your code is printing the correct answer.  If you expected a different answer, edit your question to include the answer you expected, and explain why you expected it.

#### UPDATE

Based on your revised question, it sounds like you want to convert your numbers to `double` before you divide:

```
double fraction = (double)number1 / (double)number2;
NSLog(@"fraction = %.4f", fraction);
```

Note that a `double` cannot represent all integers larger than 2<sup>53</sup> exactly.

Comment: Thanks Rob.. I'm starting to understand.  Let me rephrase my question for you.